# Young adult collection of short stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a collection of short stories that take place in the future of earth.  I can't be certain on the publish date as I read it in the late nineties, but I have the feeling it was published earlier than that.

Here are some of the stories I remember:

1) Story where some teenage girls ate some sort of snack thing that was free, but it caused them to gain weight, and there was a convenient weight loss place next door ran by the same people that cost.

2) Story where rock 'n' roll was banned, and a kid joined some sort of street gang. I just remember the end where the dad revealed he was into it as well and was a big fan of Bruce Springsteen.

3) Story where kids could wear extra ears where they could hear better, and products/items would often say things, but they had to get rid of them when they grew up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2041: Twelve Short Stories About the Future by Top Science Fiction Writers,
edited by Jane Yolen. 1990.

1. Lose Now, Pay Later by Carol Farley:

**describes two new stores at the mall--one that gives away free sweets (*swoodies*) and the other, a costly instant weight loss center.**

2. Who's Gonna Rock Us Home? by Nancy Springer
3. Ear by Jane Yolen

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?354697

Comment: Hah, just realized we're closer to the year those stories are set than the year they were published.